# Error trying to divide (÷) values ​from different pivot tables "ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names"

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I need to calculate the Conversion Rate, for that I receive two reports which I format and create 2 pivot tables and at the moment of dividing
`dfRealTase ['TC'] = dfTasaRealSales ['VolumenTotal'] / dfTasaRealPaso ['Traffic']`
I get the following ValueError error: cannot join with no overlapping index names

This I do not know what it can be is the first time that I develop in phyton, I made sure that both columns are of the same type and that they do not have NaN or inf values

```
    dfTasaRealPaso = formatTrafico()
    dfTasaRealVentas = formatVentas()
    dfTasaReal = pd.DataFrame()
    dfTasaRealPaso.dropna(inplace=True)
    dfTasaRealVentas.dropna(inplace=True)
    dfTasaRealPaso.Trafico = dfTasaRealPaso.Trafico.astype('float64')
    print(type(dfTasaRealPaso['Trafico'][0]))
    print(type(dfTasaRealVentas['VolumenTotal'][0]))
    dfTasaRealPaso = pd.pivot_table(dfTasaRealPaso, index=["ID", "month", "day", "dia_semana"], columns=["Bloque"], values=["Trafico"],fill_value=0)
    dfTasaRealVentas = pd.pivot_table(dfTasaRealVentas, index = ["CodigoEstacion", "Mes", "Dia", "Day_Week"], columns=["Hora"], values=["VolumenTotal"],fill_value=0)

    print(dfTasaRealPaso.head())
    print(dfTasaRealVentas.head())
    
    dfTasaReal['TC'] = dfTasaRealVentas['VolumenTotal']/dfTasaRealPaso['Trafico']

    print( pd.pivot_table(dfTasaReal, index = ["ID", "month", "day", "dia_semana"], columns=["Bloque"], values=["TC"], fill_value=0) )
   
    return dfTasaReal
```

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
                           Trafico
Bloque                          0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23
ID    month day dia_semana
60008 5     1   Saturday      1812  1919  1768  1725  2009  1871  1883  1974  2441  2999  3840  4563  4634  4552  4421  3983  3337  3338  3271  3155  2299  2368  2032  1965
            2   Sunday        2040  1892  1753  1652  1910  1720  1839  2024  2425  3295  4349  4292  5552  6447  6554  5618  4716  5302  4033  2177  1598  1544  1228  1043
            3   Monday         915  1075  1078  1557  1598  1958  2188  2689  2408  2781  2939  3152  2618  2603  1920  1550  2074  2107  2036  2735  2016  1869  1452  1774
            4   Tuesday       1784  1711  1715  1448  1488  1564  1911  2623  2377  3061  3181  3613  3400  3477  3039  2949  2812  4505  4387  3498  2433  1861  1635  1669
            5   Wednesday     1721  1492  1278  1180  1265  1224  1622  1974  2258  2920  3254  3279  3260  3307  3503  3833  4150  4003  3968  3073  2518  2112  2234  2016
                                 VolumenTotal                                                                    ...
Hora                                       0       1    2      3       4        5        6         7         8   ...        15        16        17        18        19        20       21       22       23   
CodigoEstacion Mes Dia Day_Week                                                                                  ...
60008          5   1   Saturday        45.403   0.000  0.0  0.000   0.000    0.000  121.599   302.913   990.649  ...  1335.588  1070.339   948.034  1222.074  1046.493   820.716  424.954   96.385  117.888   
                   2   Sunday           5.464  60.062  0.0  8.255  43.535   19.926   34.935   274.671   662.555  ...  1086.487  1354.115  1601.889  1689.020  1792.355  1414.050  384.982   97.451   46.306   
                   3   Monday           0.000   0.000  0.0  0.000  17.689   80.715  456.376  1213.109  1230.580  ...  1989.980  2290.871  3180.712  1946.372  1745.390  1480.999  692.089  230.541   22.371   
                   4   Tuesday          0.000   0.000  0.0  0.000   0.000  207.012  795.940  1034.076  1398.334  ...  1356.560  1746.760  1501.602  1504.128  1415.234  1294.313  705.502  389.561   66.634   
                   5   Wednesday        7.075  15.330  0.0  0.000   0.000   20.753  303.574   813.140  1714.702  ...   956.816  2039.040  1753.388  1838.117  1708.605  1616.878  822.072  279.777  250.937   

[5 rows x 24 columns]
```

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Automatizacion\automatization.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "\Automatizacion\automatization.py", line 12, in main
    tcReal()
  File "\Automatizacion\automatization.py", line 89, in tcReal
 packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3739, in _join_multi
    raise ValueError("cannot join with no overlapping index names")
ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names
```

Comment: try `dfTasaRealSales['VolumenTotal'].values / dfTasaRealPaso['Traffic'].values` or `dfTasaRealSales['VolumenTotal'].div(dfTasaRealPaso ['Traffic'],axis=0)`

Comment: dfTasaReal['TC'] = dfTasaRealVentas['VolumenTotal'].values/dfTasaRealPaso['Trafico'].values With this I have a different result: "ValueError: Cannot set a frame without a defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a string"
dfTasaRealVentas['VolumenTotal'].div(dfTasaRealPaso ['Traffic'],axis=0) With this I get the same error "ValueError: cannot join without overlapping index names"